# Mock scope goes beyond current test

Tags: python, mocking

I am mocking a module... here is my sample code

```
def test_validate(self):
    """Test Base Retriever Dataframe"""

    sampleQuoteClass = self.sampleQuoteClass('ThisQuote')

    bRet._getAsOfData = MagicMock(return_value=sampleQuoteClass)

    dataAsDataFrame = bVal.validate(metaDataName='MyNewQuote')
    self.assertTrue(len(dataAsDataFrame) > 0)
```

This works OK.

Problem is - bRet._getAsOfData is also mocked for the next tests, which incidentally resides in other test class.

This problem only occurs when all the tests are running together as a part of collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to [patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) the object instead of mocking it directly. You may need to adjust my example a bit to fit your code, but try something like this:

```
from mock import patch

def test_validate(self):
    """Test Base Retriever Dataframe"""

    sampleQuoteClass = self.sampleQuoteClass('ThisQuote')

    with patch('__main__.bRet') as mock_bRet:
        mock_bRet._getAsOfData.return_value = sampleQuoteClass

        dataAsDataFrame = bVal.validate(metaDataName='MyNewQuote')
        self.assertTrue(len(dataAsDataFrame) > 0)
```

When you patch the object, the mocking will be undone and the object will "go back to normal" once the `with` block exits, so the mocked state will not carry over to your other tests. It is also possible to use `patch` as a decorator, but I have always preferred to use it as a context manager. See the documentation linked above for examples of each usage.

Also, patching can be tricky in my experience, so I would suggest you read [this useful bit of documentation on "where to patch"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) as well.

Comment: Yup, I tried what you suggested. It works. You have a point though, I need to look into your suggestion if I am applying the patch in the correct location